# Route model not rendered when using filter on route change

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

I'm trying to setup mirage on a new app for testing.

ember-cli: 2.16.2

ember-cli-mirage: 0.4.0

I have a dummy test, just trying to setup mirage and verify it's working.
I would do something similar to test `route.model()`.
Using mirage's `JSONAPISerializer`, nothing in my factory and migrage-model.

```
// models/trip.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

My test :

```
import {moduleFor, test} from 'ember-qunit';
import {startMirage} from 'frontend/initializers/ember-cli-mirage';

moduleFor('route:trips.index', 'Unit | Route | trips.index', {
  needs: ['service:session', 'model:trip', 'adapter:application'],

  beforeEach() {
    this.server = startMirage();
  },

  afterEach() {
    this.server.shutdown();
  }
});

test('model', function (assert) {
  let route = this.subject();

  this.server.create('trip');

  Ember.run(() => {
    this.get('store').findAll('trip')
  });

  assert.ok(route);
});
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null
    at Class._setupRelationshipsForModel (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:196482:36)
    at Class._pushInternalModel (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:196473:10)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:196425:20
    at Backburner.run (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:20213:36)
    at Backburner.join (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:20222:33)
    at Class._push (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:196397:50)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:192955:18
    at tryCatcher (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:63559:21)
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:63737:33)
    at publish (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:63723:9)
```

Works fine on development/production and using a real server to get the data.

If i dont create my record with mirage, there is no exception.

Looks like the problem only occurs within `Ember.run`

Removing `Ember.run` will not raise the exception, but I need it to test properly (and avoid errors like `You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in a run`)...

Comment: If it does not raise exception without `Ember.run`, why do you need to use it, then?

Comment: Sometimes I must use `Ember.run`, otherwise I get this error "You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in a run" -- which makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @rstellar here https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage/issues/1220#issuecomment-350155703 a working solution is to use async/await around the function.

This problem happens when we try to set up relationships after the store has been destroyed. This solution will prevent this from happening until the end of the function.

Here is the working code:

```
import {moduleFor, test} from 'ember-qunit';
import wait from 'ember-test-helpers/wait'; // import wait from ember here
import {startMirage} from 'frontend/initializers/ember-cli-mirage';

moduleFor('route:trips.index', 'Unit | Route | trips.index', {
  needs: ['service:session', 'model:trip', 'adapter:application'],

  beforeEach() {
    this.server = startMirage();
  },

  afterEach() {
    this.server.shutdown();
  }
});

test('model', async function (assert) { // Declare this function as async 
  let route = this.subject();

  this.server.create('trip');

  Ember.run(() => {
    this.get('store').findAll('trip')
  });

  assert.ok(route);

  await wait(); // The actual wait
});
```

A PR is open on Ember to make the error more explicit about this.

Answer (score 0):

`store.findAll` returns a promise. try resolving the promise and run your assertion inside a `.then()`

(ignoring the fact that this is not the way to test a route, but i understand you are just using this test to work something out with your mirage setup)

Comment: Thank you Christopher, unfortunately this is not working, see the suggested solution here: https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage/issues/1220#issuecomment-350155703 Can you explain why this is not a good way to unit test a route? Yes it's a dummy example here but what I did I the end is unit-testing that the route's model function returns the correct records.